# Applying a different logo for each color scheme in a WordPress theme through stylesheets

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm making a WordPress theme which has separate color schemes which are loaded through a secondary CSS file. I would like to use a different color logo for each color scheme, but I'm not sure the best way to go about it.

The logo currently uses the img tag, and I'm using the standard max-width: 100%; height: auto; to make it responsive. I would like to retain the responsive aspect, but I want the logo's URL to be handled through the stylesheet, so that it can be easily switched for each color scheme. However, if I replace the img with a div, I can not figure out how to make it responsive using the background-image property, without specifying specific dimensions. I don't want to specify exact dimensions to allow for different logo sizes.

Is there any way to do it like this, or am I just going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use logo in background and while using different stylesheet, use different path of logo.
as in red.css

```
.logo{
background:url(images/redlogo.png)
}
```

and in blue.css

```
.logo{
    background:url(images/bluelogo.png)
    }
```

Comment: This is what I would like to do, but how can I make it responsive using an image as a background and not specifying height or width?

Comment: You can try using height and width and it works well in responsive designs as well.

Comment: But I cannot allow for different logo sizes by specifying the height and width. I want it to be responsive no matter size logo is used, which can be easily achieved with max-width: 100%; height: auto; for imgs, but I don't know how to achieve the same effect when using background-image.

Comment: Use min height, min width, max height and max width.

Comment: Using pixel values for the min/max height and width? What background-size setting also? I've tried by setting a min width/height of a set pixel value like 100px, but it just always renders the image at that size, and doesn't take into account the max values. I've used background-size: auto & 100%, I'm not sure what else would work.